# Shell error: Value too great for base (error token is "168a")

Tags: bash, shell

I get this error message for my shell script below:

```
./my_script.sh line 17: f1bfab2e-168a: value too great for base (error token is "168a")
```

```
data=($( jq -r '.data' data.json  | tr -d '[]," ' ))

for i in "${data[@]}"; do
  echo "${data[i]}"
done
```

(`data` is made up of array elements that are a series of letters and numbers such as `f1bfab2e-168a-4da7-9677-5018e5f97g0f` )

I've referenced other Stack Overflow posts that provide solutions such as [variable indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697037/0999-value-too-great-for-base-error-token-is-0999) or characters getting interpreted as [octal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777597/value-too-great-for-base-error-token-is-08) but I have been unable to resolve this error.

When using variable indirection such as

```
data=($( jq -r '.data' data.json  | tr -d '[]," ' ))

for i in "${data[@]}"; do
  echo "${data[${!i}]}"
done
```

`"${data[${!i}]}"` ends up only referencing the first array element for some reason. So if my array has two elements `abc123` and `bcd234`, then what gets printed is just
`abc123` `abc123`
instead of
`abc123` `bcd234`.
I don't exactly understand why and what's going on there.

Additionally, I don't think that bash is interpreting any of my characters as octal numbers here so a solution for that situation does not apply to my case.

What significance does `168a` have to bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` is already the item of the array, not the index, as you seem to believe. This should work:

```
for i in "${data[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Omg /facepalm. What a rookie mistake. Thank you!